# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d   = {1: 1}

def nterms(n):
    if n in d: return d[n]
    else:
        if n%2: d[n] = 1+nterms(3*n+1)
        else: d[n] = 1+nterms(n/2)

print (max((nterms(n),n) for n in range(2,10**6)))
```

Выдаёт ошибку **"Traceback (most recent call last)"** и далее следует **"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'"**, как я понял происходит слишком много вызовов.

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из функции всегда нужно что-то возвращать, если вы потом используете её результат. У вас в ветке `else:` ничего не возвращается (а значит, возвращается `None` с точки зрения питона). Если я правильно понимаю, вам везде нужно возвращать `d[n]`, поэтому, чтобы не писать одинаковые `return`-ы во всех ветках, проще инвертировать условие и сначала посчитать `d[n]`, если оно ещё не посчитано, а потом вернуть его в любом случае:

```
def nterms(n):
    if n not in d:
        if n%2: 
            d[n] = 1+nterms(3*n+1)
        else: 
            d[n] = 1+nterms(n/2)
    return d[n]
```

Теперь функция всегда возвращает `d[n]`, при любом `n`.